# Newspaper3k returns 0 articles from archive.org waybackmachine pages whereas the live page works as expected

Tags: python, python-newspaper

When attempting to use the python library newspaper3 on an archived page url from archive.org it fails to fetch any articles. However when using it on the same live page url it works fine. Please see below:

```
import newspaper

len(newspaper.build('https://bbc.co.uk/news').articles)
>> 111

len(newspaper.build('https://web.archive.org/web/http://www.bbc.co.uk/news').articles)
>>> 0
```

Even using the special `id` hack that returns the original modified page doesn't work:

```
len(newspaper.build('https://web.archive.org/web/20171219030622id_/http://www.bbc.co.uk/news').articles)
    >>> 0
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find no indication that this library is meant to work with archive.org, or that it works with archive.org.

Both [[1]](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/blob/master/newspaper/resources/misc/google_sources.txt)[[2]](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/blob/master/newspaper/resources/misc/popular_sources.txt) lists of sources contain no mention of either `archive.org` or `web.archive.org`.

I downloaded the entire [repository](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper) to search the source code, and it also contains no mention of either Internet Archive domain.

From what I can tell based on [this file](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/blob/master/newspaper/source.py), the `articles` attribute is based on RSS/ATOM feeds. I don't think Internet Archive archives those, and even if it does, since they would link back to the live version of the site, some changes in the library itself would be needed to get them to work with Internet Archive.

[You've already opened an issue](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/issues/490), where you specify it doesn't work at all (even on single articles -- this is probably an issue elsewhere, such as in the node scoring algorithm it uses to decide which nodes contain the article) so if you don't want to dive into the library source code and fix it yourself, all you can do is wait.

Comment: There are 139 open issues currently, it's safe to say that my particular issue is never going to be addressed. Thanks for attempting to help.

Comment: @Derek Right...I really think that fulfilling this request for you would require a lengthy pull request to Newspaper3k, and that's too far out of the scope of a Stack Overflow question. I believe I figured out *how* to fix this in general terms based on my above answer, but it's up to you to actually do it.

Comment: Thanks Fred, I was just a little annoyed at the work that needed to be done in order to get what I needed, your answer was sound.